# WMI: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA) throws when try to connect to remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I'm using the following code to connect to remote machine using WMI:

```
   ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
            connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
            connOptions.Username = "admin";
            connOptions.Password = "password";
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", remoteMachine), connOptions);
            scope.Connect();
```

I'm getting the following exception: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Checked all steps described [in this knowledgebase article](http://www.s-code.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=14), everything is OK on remote machine.

User is Administrator on remote machine.

Tried Wbemtest tool, the same result

Does anyone has an idea what is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to WMI: 0x800706ba errors on some machines (but not all)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369177/connecting-to-wmi-0x800706ba-errors-on-some-machines-but-not-all)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you under Win7 you must run app as an administrator.  You can also try different values for connOptions.Impersonation property.  Did you open RPC port on a remote machine?  Try turning off firewall altogeter on both machines.

Comment: If it works with firewalls being disabled then try typing at the command prompt: Netsh firewall set service RemoteAdmin

Comment: Good suggestions. Thanks. Configured my firewalls a little bit and everything works fine

Comment: Or you could add WMI as exception to your firewall

Answer (score 4):

Also, You need to enable Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) rule in windows firewall.

> 1] Windows Firewall.
>   2] Allow app or feature through windows firewall.
>   3] Enable Privilege for Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI).

**To enable or disable WMI rule using Windows firewall**

> 1. In the **Control Panel**, click **Security** and then **click Windows Firewall.**
> 2. Click **Change Settings** and then **click the Exceptions tab.**
> 3. In the **Exceptions window**, select the check box for **Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI)** to enable WMI traffic through **the
>      firewall**.
>
> To **disable WMI traffic**, clear the check box.

**You can also enable or disable WMI traffic through the firewall at the command prompt.**

To **enable or disable WMI traffic** at **command prompt using WMI** rule group

**Use the following commands at a command prompt. Type the following to enable WMI traffic through the firewall.**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
```

**Type the following command to disable WMI traffic through the firewall.**

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=no
```

Comment: In my case I was trying to kill java.exe process on a remote server via WMI using C#. This solution worked well for me. Thanks!

Comment: Enable Privilege = enable WMI traffic through the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Still you have problem then follow below link may help you.

[Connecting to WMI Remotely](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854)

I facing this issue even my **all firewall is off**.

Below command run and my problem is solved.

> 1. netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="windows management
>    instrumentation (wmi)" new enable=yes
> 2. netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in name="DCOM"
>    program=%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe service=rpcss action=allow
>    protocol=TCP localport=135
> 3. netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in name ="WMI"
>    program=%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe service=winmgmt action =
>    allow protocol=TCP localport=any
> 4. netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=in name ="UnsecApp" program=%systemroot%\system32\wbem\unsecapp.exe action=allow
> 5. netsh advfirewall firewall add rule dir=out name ="WMI_OUT"
>    program=%systemroot%\system32\svchost.exe service=winmgmt action=allow
>    protocol=TCP localport=any