# The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Tags: networking, powershell

Occasionally I get this error when working on remote computers.  It's hit or miss on which computer I get it on.  But I am able to ping the computer and test-connection pans out.  For example, the computer I got this error on today I was able to get to yesterday.  I know the computer is on because It's right next me.

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At line:1 char:14
+ get-wmiObject <<<<  -Class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $current -Authentication 6 -credential $credential | Invoke-WMIMethod -name Win32Shutdown
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657724/wmi-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706ba-throws

Comment: In my case, the Logon Account was faulty. Need to make sure it is declared like domain\username and also need to make sure the username is still active in the domain.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check to see if the `Remote Procedure Call (RPC)` service is running.  If it is, then it's a firewall issue between your workstation and the server.  You can test it by temporary disabling the firewall and retrying the command.

Edit after comment:

Ok, it's a firewall issue.  You'll have to either limit the ports WMI/RPC work on, or open a lot of ports in the McAfee firewall.

Here are a few sites that explain this:

1. [Microsoft KB for limiting ports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/154596)
2. [McAfee site talking about the same thing](https://community.mcafee.com/thread/44646)

Comment: It is running.  I noticed when I disable McAfee Firewall I do not get this error.

Answer (score 6):

You may get your answer here: [Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330874/get-wmiobject-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706?rq=1)

**UPDATE**

It might be due to various issues.I cant say which one is there in your case. It may be because:

- DCOM is not enabled in host pc or target pc or on both
- your firewall or even your antivirus is preventing the access
- any WMI related service is disabled

Some WMI related services are:

- Remote Access Auto Connection Manager
- Remote Access Connection Manager
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
- Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator
- Remote Registry

For DCOM settings refer to registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\OLE`, value `EnableDCOM`. The **value should be set to 'Y'**.

Answer (score 1):

My problem turned out to be blank spaces in the txt file that I was using to feed the WMI Powershell script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to run a PowerShell script that only looked at a remote server to read the size of a hard disk.

I turned off the Firewall (Domain networks, Private networks, and Guest or public network) on the remote server and the script worked.

I then turned the Firewall for Domain networks back on, and it worked.

I then turned the Firewall for Private network back on, and it also worked.

I then turned the Firewall for Guest or public networks, and it also worked.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is reading this eons later. My problem was I deployed a GPO a few months ago that disables printer spooling via Windows Firewall rules. One of the rules is "File and printer sharing (Spooler Service - RPC-EPMAP)". This was set to deny.

This blocked the "RPC Endpoint Mapper" port range inbound and didn't specify a service. As a result this was blocking all traffic inbound on all RPC ports (tcp 1024-5000).

Disables the rule and this magically started working again.

TLDR; You need to allow the RPC Endpoint Mapper port range inbound on Windows firewall (tcp 1024-500) along with the WMI-In rule.

Answer (score 0):

Duting create cluster, my error was:

```
An error occurred while creating the cluster.
Could not determine Management Point Network Type.

The RPC server is unavailable
```

Solution:

```
Server Manager
Local Server
Click on one of the network adapter links, like "Ethernet".
Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections
Right click on the first network adapter
Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
Properties
Advanced
DNS
Click radio button:
Append primary and connection specific DNS suffixes
```