# Error exporting to PDF (RPC server is unavailable)

Tags: c++, pdf, crystal-reports

First of all, sorry for my English, it's not my first language.

I have a problem testing my C++ Builder 2007 applications in a Windows 8 HP tablet, when I try to export a Crystal Reports archive to PDF. It works in two computers with the same operating system, but in the tablet it shows the following error: "System Error. Code: 1722. The RPC server is unavailable"

The code is simple, as it seen:

```
            crystal->ExportOptions->FileType = AdobeAcrobatPDF;
            crystal->ExportOptions->FileName = this->archivo;
            crystal->Export();
```

I try changing the process from Export() to Print(), and the result is the same. Whereas a random third party program exports correctly.

I have found some answers on the Internet, but they don't help me. I already have running the print spooler and RPC/WMI services like they sais in [The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922033/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706ba) and other websites. I have disabled the firewall and change the registry like said in the Microsoft link from http://scn.sap.com/thread/2135299 (although it's all in local, even the tablet isn't in the network) and I'm using an administrator local account. Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, it was the setting previous to exporting:

```
crystal->Printer->Orientation = orLandscape;
```

Without that line, it works.