# Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer "server name". The RPC server is unavailable

Tags: c#, impersonation, servicecontroller

I have been trying to solve this issue and unfortunately still not successful. I can access the Server remotely and have rights to the server. We are on the same domain but unfortunately when my program is trying to control the server services is when I get this error. The RPC Server is unavailable.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (new Impersonation("domain", "Server", "Password"))
        {
            Control myControl = new Control("ServiceName", "Server");
            // do whatever you want

            myControl.StopService();
        }
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Here is the impersonation code. I found this code on another form in StackOverFlow but still having issues.

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
public class Impersonation : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SafeTokenHandle _handle;
    private readonly WindowsImpersonationContext _context;

    const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

    public Impersonation(string domain, string username, string password)
    {
        var ok = LogonUser(username, domain, password,
                       LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, 0, out this._handle);
        if (!ok)
        {
            var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Could not impersonate the elevated user.  LogonUser returned error code {0}.", errorCode));
        }

        this._context = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(this._handle.DangerousGetHandle());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this._context.Dispose();
        this._handle.Dispose();
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true) { }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Code from the Control Class.

```
    public Control(string serviceName, string computerName)
    {
        service = new ServiceController("serviceName", "ServerName");
    }

    public bool StopService()
    {

        try
        {
            if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
            {
                service.Stop();
                return true;
            }

            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} --> already stopped", service.DisplayName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), @"Error Stopping Service");
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Possibly this question will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922033/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706ba