# Powershell GET-ADComputer list and foreach Get WMI_Networkconf

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory, wmi

I'm simply trying to get all the Computers out of the AD and want to show me the IP,  DNS Name, Mac-Address and description.

I got the WMI part working for my local computer but as soon as I try it with the AD Computer list its throwing around errors which i'm not able to solve myself.

I know that WMI reading is granted in our internal Network as we also use WMI Monitoring.

Powershell Code:

```
$computerlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | select Name
  foreach($c in $computerlist)
  {
    try
    {
      gwmi -class "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -ComputerName $c |
      select DNSHostName, MACAddress, IPAddress, Description |
      where IPAddress -NotLike "" |
      where Description -NotLike "VMware*"
    }

    catch
    {
      Write-Warning "$c is unreachable!"
    }
  }
```

Comment: What are the error messages you are getting?

Comment: [1] a pipe does NOT work at the start of a line - only in or at the _end_ of a line. [*grin*] ///// [2] take a look at the content of your `$C` variable. i suspect it is an AD object, not simple computer name. you likely need to use `$C.<PropertyName>` where the prop name is whatever your `$C` object contains.

Comment: @HAL9256 RCP-Server is not availabe HRESULT: 0x800706BA

Comment: @Lee_Dailey [1] was a "graphical" thing as the line would be very long [2] i did this and it works now for some name's but still more errors then passes

Comment: posting code that DOES NOT WORK is kinda silly when you are asking for help with your code. [*grin*] PoSh knows to continue after a pipe, so you can line wrap after that. ///// please show the code you are discussing ... right now i have no idea what your code actually is ... [*sigh ...*]

Comment: "RCP-Server is not available" is the generic error for WMI can't connect. It could be the machine is off, RPC ports are blocked, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and report back...

```
# Use a basic WMI connection check before checking the Network Adapter details
(Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name | 
foreach {
    If((gwmi -ComputerName $PSItem -Class win32_process))
    {
        try
        {
            gwmi -class 'Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration' -ComputerName $PSItem | 
            select DNSHostName, MACAddress, IPAddress, Description |
            where IPAddress -NotLike "" | 
            where Description -NotLike '*VMware*'
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning "When processing $PSItem, some other error occurred!"
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Warning -Message "WMI connection failed for host $PSItem, thus not reachable"
    }
}
```

Update for the OP

As for …

> Thx for the suggestion but i still get the same error message
>   (HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

As stated by others, the RPC is not a PowerShell specific thing, it's a service / resource level thing.

[See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922033/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706ba)

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but i still get the same error message (HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: As far as i can see the most clients dont run the WMI service, as all our servers that are monitored are now fully running, but not the clients...
therefor i need to script the start of the WMI service before or via GPO.

Comment: i got the pc's running the wmi
i have found out that those who are not responding are thin clients running a linux system

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is with the `For` loop. Passing the name `$c` is not passing in the name as the actual computer name, but as a custom PS Object. You can see this if you do a  `Write-Host`:

```
$computerlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | select Name
foreach($c in $computerlist)
{
  Write-Host $c
}

@{Name=C1234}
```

You simply need to reference the Property e.g. `$c.Name` so your code looks like:

```
$computerlist = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | select Name
foreach($c in $computerlist)
{
  try
  {
    gwmi -class "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -ComputerName $c.Name `
    |select DNSHostName, MACAddress, IPAddress, Description `
    |where IPAddress -NotLike "" `
    |where Description -NotLike "VMware*" `
  }
  catch
  {
    Write-Warning "$c is unreachable!"
  }
}
```

Comment: thx for the info, now it works for some of the entries but sadly not for all bringing the same error

Comment: it is still the same (HRESULT: 0x800706BA)